# Active link hover area changes/error?

Tags: css, menu, hover, shopify, liquid

My website is www.teamanco.com  I'm having trouble with the hover on my nested menu. If you go to the second level, it's fine, but the menu in the third level has a messed up selection/hover.  Help?  I have no idea where to start. I'm built on shopify.

```
}
.main-nav {
  float: left;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
  width: 100%;
}
.main-nav > li:hover > ul {
  -webkit-opacity: 1;
  -moz-opacity: 1;
  opacity: 1;
  height: auto;
  overflow: visible;
}
.main-nav > li:hover > ul > li:hover > a {
  color: {{ settings.main_nav_link_hover }};
  background-color: #eaeaea;
}
.main-nav > li:hover > ul > li:hover > ul {
  -webkit-opacity: 1;
  -moz-opacity: 1;
  opacity: 1;
  height: auto;
  overflow: visible;
}
.main-nav > li:hover > ul > li:hover > ul > li:hover > a {
  color: {{ settings.main_nav_link_hover }};
  background-color: #eaeaea;
}
.main-nav > li:hover > ul > li:hover > ul > li:hover > ul {
  -webkit-opacity: 1;
  -moz-opacity: 1;
  opacity: 1;
  height: auto;
  overflow: visible;
}
.main-nav > li:hover > ul > li:hover > ul > li:hover > ul > li:hover > a {
  color: {{ settings.main_nav_link_hover }};
  background-color: #eaeaea;
}
.main-nav > li:hover > ul > li:hover > ul > li:hover > ul > li:hover > ul {
  -webkit-opacity: 1;
  -moz-opacity: 1;
  opacity: 1;
  height: auto;
  overflow: visible;
}
.main-nav > li:hover > ul > li:hover > ul > li:hover > ul > li:hover > ul > li:hover > a {
  color: {{ settings.main_nav_link_hover }};
  background-color: #eaeaea;
}
.main-nav > li:hover > ul > li:hover > ul > li:hover > ul > li:hover > ul > li:hover > ul {
  -webkit-opacity: 1;
  -moz-opacity: 1;
  opacity: 1;
  height: auto;
  overflow: visible;
}
.main-nav > li {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 60px;
  border-top: solid 2px transparent;
  margin-top: -2px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  position: relative;
}
.main-nav > li:first-child {
  margin-left: 0px;
}
.main-nav > li.active {
  border-top: solid 2px {{ settings.main_nav_link }};
}
.main-nav > li.active > a {
  color: {{ settings.main_nav_link_hover }};
}
.main-nav > li:hover {
  border-top: solid 2px {{ settings.main_nav_link }};
}
.main-nav > li:hover > a {
  color: {{ settings.main_nav_link_hover }};
}
.main-nav > li > a {
  font-family: "{{ settings.secondary_font }}", Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding:12px 0px 11px;
  float:left;
  color: {{ settings.main_nav_link }};
  text-decoration: none;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
}
.main-nav > li > a.has-dropdown {
  position: relative;
}
.main-nav > li > a.has-dropdown:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  border-right: 4px solid transparent;
  border-top: 4px solid {{ settings.main_nav_link }};
  border-left: 4px solid transparent;
  border-top-color: {{ settings.main_nav_link }};
  top: 7px;
  right: -14px;
}
.main-nav > li > ul {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0px;
  width: 150px;
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  padding: 10px 0;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 6px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.175);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 6px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.175);
  box-shadow: 0 6px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.175);
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  z-index: 201;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0 0 4px 4px;
  -webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
  -moz-border-radius: 0 0 4px 4px;
  -moz-background-clip: padding;
  border-radius: 0 0 4px 4px;
  background-clip: padding-box;
  height: 0;
  -webkit-opacity: 0;
  -moz-opacity: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.4s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.4s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: opacity 0.4s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: opacity 0.4s ease-in-out;
  transition: opacity 0.4s ease-in-out;
}
.main-nav > li > ul > li {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}
.main-nav > li > ul > li:hover > a {
  color: {{ settings.main_nav_link_hover }};
  background-color: #eaeaea;
}
.main-nav > li > ul > li > a {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  font-family: "{{ settings.secondary_font }}", Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: {{ settings.main_nav_link }};
  text-decoration: none;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
}
.main-nav > li > ul > li ul {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 100%;
  width: 150px;
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  padding: 10px 0;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 6px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.175);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 6px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.175);
  box-shadow: 0 6px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.175);
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  z-index: 200;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0 0 4px 4px;
  -webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
  -moz-border-radius: 0 0 4px 4px;
  -moz-background-clip: padding;
  border-radius: 0 0 4px 4px;
  background-clip: padding-box;
  height: 0;
  -webkit-opacity: 0;
  -moz-opacity: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.4s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.4s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: opacity 0.4s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: opacity 0.4s ease-in-out;
  transition: opacity 0.4s ease-in-out;
}
.main-nav > li > ul > li ul li {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}
.main-nav > li > ul > li ul li a {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  font-family: "{{ settings.secondary_font }}", Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: {{ settings.main_nav_link }};
  text-decoration: none;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you move your mouse left and right across the top navigation level, you'll see the same problem you described when you hover over the second level. A skinny grey box appears to hang around momentarily after you move your mouse away and the list has disappeared. It's caused by the padding on the `<ul>` tags. Remove these lines and see if that fixes the issue:

```
.main-nav > li > ul {
  ...
  padding: 10px 0;
  ...
}

.main-nav > li > ul > li ul {
  ...
  padding: 10px 0;
  ...
}
```

It appears as though the list items (`<li>`) disappear instantly when you move your mouse away, but the opacity of the `<ul>` (which only contains padding now) fades away with the transition.